# Usage of custom data types on client and server wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a custom datatype I put in a class Library SharedTypes

```
namespace SharedTypes
{
    public class District
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then have a WCF server with this service

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using SharedTypes;

namespace WCF.WCFInterfaces
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWcfService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        District GetDistrict(long id);

        [OperationContract]
        void CreateDistrict(District district);

        [OperationContract]
        List<District> GetDistricts();
     }
}
```

On the client side I have a Interface (So I inject the implementation)

```
using SharedTypes;

namespace WcfInterfaces
{
    public interface IDistrictManager
    {
        void CreateDistrict(District district);
        District GetDistrict(long id);
        List<District> GetDistricts();
    }
}
```

I finally have the implementation the client should use

```
public class DistrictManager : IDistrictManager
{
    private readonly WcfServiceClient _salesService;
    public DistrictManager()
    {
        _salesService = new WcfServiceClient();
    }

    public void CreateDistrict(District district)
    {
        _salesService.CreateDistrictAsync(district);
    }

    public District GetDistrict(long id)
    {
        return _salesService.GetDistrict(id);
    }

    public List<District> GetDistricts()
    {
        var list = _salesService.GetDistricts();
        return list.ToList();
    }
}
```

But here the problem arises, this implementation expects to use a version of District it gets from the service reference

```
WcfClientLibrary.SalesService.District
```

Instead of

```
SharedTypes.District
```

They are the same, but VS dont know that

So I get errors that the interface is not properly implemented because I have 2 different types of the District class.

How can I get the Service reference to use the SharedTypes.District instead? Or is it my way of implementing it that is way off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click your **service reference** in **client project** and check "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies".

Be sure that you have added `SharedTypes.District` to your client service reference project.

Comment: Is the way I am doing it ok? Or are there things I should reconsider?

Comment: I think your implementation is Ok; but there is no need to convert your enumerables to list in the server side... (although it is not a problem at all).

Comment: Well the GetDistricts() returns an array on the client side so I have to do it, I guess the serilization dont work properly for collections of custom types?

Comment: well, I may say yes; as long as you do not mark them to return a specific type. you may refer to the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525463/why-does-my-wcf-service-return-and-array-instead-of-a-list-t

Comment: I had to right click on service reference from the client project and choose configure service reference. Once I opened it was already checked to reuse types in referenced assemblies. I clicked ok and then it started working. Really weird!

Answer (score 2):

When adding your WCF reference on the client side. Click on the advanced options.
There is a setting that you can specify to tell it to re-use types from specified assembly(s).
You'll be able to specify the assembly(s).