# C# send data from Windows Forms to WCF service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

Can i send a List from windows form to a wcf service? I'm using wcf web service.
I'm reading from a file in form and i want to send result to service.

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
List<double> fileResult = new List<double>();
while(!file.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = file.ReadLine();
    lines.Add(line);

}
file.Close();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)                
{                
    fileResult.Add(Convert.ToDouble(lines[i]));                   
}
```

Comment: Where is the code to send the data to the service?

Comment: There is no issue whatsoever talking from winforns to a service. A tool like wcf is a reasonable place to start. So... Yes?

Comment: Of course you can! Assuming you have all your web services already set up. Keep in mind passing a List to the service might get a bit _tricky_. I would suggest converting the List to an **Array**

Comment: @Zinthos (and OP): you might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525463/why-does-my-wcf-service-return-and-array-instead-of-a-list-t).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

However, you'll want to send/receive it either as an `IEnumerable<double>` or a `double[]`

As for **HOW** (which you didn't ask) you may use this as a reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18789/A-Quick-and-Dirty-WCF-Service-and-Client-Using-WCF

Comment: I will use .toArray to send array, but how i can do that?

Comment: So if i undestand ok i must have in service a method get and set and in form only set the array i want to send. I'll try. Thank you so much!